# Как менять вес нейрона смещения. Обратное распространение ошибки

Tags: математика, нейронные-сети

Во всех статьях про нейронные сети и их обучение, с помощью обратного распространения ошибки, описывается как находить изменения для весов простых нейронов. Но нигде не могу найти, как находить изменения для весов нейронов смещения(Они же bias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так же как остальные веса,но надо в формулах учитывать что сигнал на них +1.
Смотрите,уточню,рассматриваем слой (2,3)-2 ряда,3 элемента,3 входных нейрона полносвязно соединяются с 2 нейронами,1 элемент в матрице это вес биаса,с правого слоя приходит ошибки градиентов как (1,3) - 1 ряд и 3 элемента.Мы спокойно можем положить его на матрицу (2,3),пусть она будет new_matr,тогда

```
upd_matr+=l_r*<0-й элемент +1 - вектор входных сигналов как (3,1).T=(1,3)>(X:=<матричный продукт>)<градиент ошибок как (1,3)>,где l_r - коэффициент обучения.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это я описал обновление матрицы,а нахождение градиента ошибок для слоя (1) из слоя(2) на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, можно еще вопрос по нейросетям. Если обучать сеть с большим кол-вом нейронов(Что означает огромное множество весов), то при расчете сигмоидной функции она может выдать строго 0 или строго 1. Скажите, как это решить?

Comment: Сигмоида в диапазоне от 0 до 1 выдает,т.е оттуда вещественное число.С большим количеством нейронов может на них накапливаться большие значение,в точках связей к данному нейрону и сигмоида может выдавать NaN это будет если решение не сходится - не та инициализация или коэффициент обучения.

Comment: @Константин Просто я решил при помощи моей нейронной сети задачу про Ирисы Фишера и, хотел попробовать решить задачу на распознавание рукописных цифр. Если на первой все было здорово, то на второй, сколько бы я сеть не обучал при любых входных данных одинаковые значения. И я не понимаю, то ли я алгоритм обучения не правильно написал, то ли гиперпараметры не те. Не знаете как проверить правильность кода?

Comment: Ну выкладите код,интересно посмотреть.Вот здесь еще посмотрите материал:https://github.com/kosta2222/simpleNNforSover/blob/master/desc.txt

Comment: @Константин https://github.com/SSL0/NeuralNetwork Только код на плюсах. Я знаю, что на Python все удобнее, проще, быстрее.

Comment: Попробую посмотреть.

Comment: @Константин Ну что скажете?

Comment: Это у вас в классе Neuron не хватает double e-это будет результат матричного умножение сигналов на связи и запишется в e,оно используется в обратном распространениии,производная от него берется.Можете дать email,может пообщаемся по коду,познакомимся,меня ИНС тоже интересуют)